# T-SQL Query doesn't work with DATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have the following table, named `E_TARIFFE`:

[image: Table 1]

If I run the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM E_TARIFFE 
WHERE COD_EVENTO = 1 
AND PAGAMENTO_UNICO = 1 
AND VALIDA_DAL >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) -- Today, 2016-11-07
AND VALIDA_AL <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

The query doesn't return any row. Why?
I expect the line 3 in output...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the logic backwards:

```
WHERE COD_EVENTO = 1 AND
      PAGAMENTO_UNICO = 1 AND
      VALIDA_DAL <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND -- Today, 2016-11-07
      VALIDA_AL >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Although I'm not a fan of `BETWEEN` with dates, you might follow this better as:

```
 WHERE COD_EVENTO = 1 AND
      PAGAMENTO_UNICO = 1 AND
      CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN VALIDA_DAL AND VALIDA_AL
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your VALIDA_DAL date values are less than today's date. This would return no rows.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean, what do I mean? He asked why his query does not return any rows. This is the reason why.

Comment: I suppose with the assumption that the table really only had 4 rows. It answers why row 3 didn't return, just a rather wide assumption on the data-set as a whole.

Comment: Well if his initial query wasn't returning any rows, that tells me exactly what the entire dataset looks like.